# open jqgrid column link in jquery model

Tags: jqgrid

```
name:'copyquiz',align:'center',classes:'s',index:'copyquiz',width:'100%',formatter:'showlink',formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'copy.php'}
```

Right now, this opens the new page. How do I get this page to open in a jQuery modal on the same page (like a popup window)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the jquery fancy box css and javascript file and include in your file

1. jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js
2. jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css

And then add the class name like "box it"  wherever you want the jquery model and there add the class name like "boxit" and then try.

Your clickable will be open with the popup.

Comment: you should just use target="_blank"attribute in the <a>. The standard 'showlink' formatter supports target attribute.